# validating HTML: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control

Tags: html, validating

I don't know why I keep getting this error while checking my page at http://validator.w3.org/check The error was:

```
Line 235, Column 84: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.
… <label for="name" style="line-height:24px;">Your Name</label><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

here is my actual code

```
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="name" style="line-height:24px;">Your Name</label><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="css_form_namefield TooltipIstok " type="text" name="name" value="" style="width: 554px;" maxlength="50" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use the for attribute in a label element it has to match the id of an input element in your form.

ie

```
<label for="field-id" style="line-height:24px;">Your Name</label><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="field-id">
```

This page may be helpful for more information. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: here is my code               <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <label for="name" style="line-height:24px;">Your Name</label><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <input class="css_form_namefield TooltipIstok " type="text" name="name" value="" style="width: 554px;" maxlength="50" >
                                    </div>

Comment: This answer is wrong. You have to match the id, not the name. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element. The answer below this is correct.

Answer (score 11):

By definition, the [`for` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-for) value must match the `id` attribute value of “another” form control, to use the HTML 4.01 terminology. [Controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.2) are created by `input`, `textarea`, `button`, `select`, or `object` elements, so just read “another” as “a”. HTML5 puts this somewhat differently, specifying that the attribute must refer to a [labelable element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label).

From the error message, it seems that you are validating against HTML5, so the rule that applies is that the `for` attribute must refer to a `button`, `input` (other than with `type=hidden`), `keygen`, `meter`, `output`, `progress`, `select`, or `textarea` element. My guess is that you just forgot the `id` attribute, incorrectly assuming that the `name` attribute could do its job.